# State machine workflow delay problem

Tags: workflow, state-machine

I have a state machine workflow (see below)
[image]

When i start the workflow first log is made.
By debuggging, the Debugger does not step into 
the delay.

The workflow completes always, BUT the second log is NEVER made!

No error